# Monitor doesn't work with ParallelTable

Tags: parallelization, monitoring

I can't monitor ParallelTable:

```
Monitor[ParallelTable[Pause[3]; i, {i, 1, 10}], i]
```

just displays `i` until it is finished.

Do you guys know of alternatives?

Comment: Can you expand your question with what happens when you try? Are error messages generated? Does it just not do anything?

Comment: BTW the reason is that `ParallelTable` might send values to process to subkernels in batches (depending on the `Method` setting), so the table iterator variable does not get values sequentially as in the case of `Table`.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think his question relates to the fact that `Monitor[ParallelTable[expr, {i, 1, 10}], i]` just displays `i` until it's finished

Comment: @acl I got that but the point is that it is not immediately clear what the question is asking unless one has already encountered the problem.  I have seen the problem, but I have not taken the time to work out a practical solution yet (one that does not significantly hurt performance I mean---it's possible to send progress back to the main kernel, but the communication cost can be significant)

Comment: @Szabolcs Actually I was more asking you how `ParallelTable` possibly sending batches of expressions to each kernel explains this (as I don't understand) rather than clarifying his answer...

Comment: @Valerio I have tried to make your question more explicit. Hope you don't mind. If I misunderstood feel free to undo the changes and explain what you're asking better.

Comment: @acl if you look at the [Method option here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Parallelize.html) that'll give some hints, sorry for being so terse.  I'll write up a reply later tonight if no one else will.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm intimately familiar with these options :) But I am afraid I still don't see how they relate to the question (which I also had for some time). Looking forward to any answers.

Comment: A [related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352461/monitoring-progress-of-a-parallel-computation-in-mathematica).

Comment: @Eli why don't you improve it and make it an answer?  It'd be an improvement over Leonid's.

Comment: @Szabolcs I was answering precisely what was asked. The SO answer is very nice (I wasn't aware of it), but answers a slightly different question.

Comment: @Szabolcs It's a little daunting suggesting an answer after Leonid has had a shot at it, but what the heck...

Comment: @Leonid and Eli When I said "a bit nicer" I was referring to the effort for reducing communication between the main kernel and subkernels, but I might be wrong that it works at all ...

Comment: @Szabolcs and Eli It seems like a good approach if the question is really about *only* monitoring progress, and reducing overhead. I simply interpreted it as it was written, more generally - that it was about monitoring stuff inside `ParallelTable`, not necessarily only progress.

Comment: @Eli I don't know much about parallel computations in Mathematica, so I don't expect my answers in this domain to be particularly valuable :). Your answer seems a good option, I don't vote now since have no time right now to test. From the look at it, you may have missed a `HoldAll` attribute though.

Answer (score 38):

One way is to set a shared variable that would be assigned to an iterator variable, and monitor that:

```
SetSharedVariable[j]
Monitor[
   ParallelTable[j = n;Length[FactorInteger[2^n - 1]], {n, 50, 300}], 
   j
]
```

This may make sense if the computation for each `i` is rather intensive, so that the overhead of communication with the main kernel is negligible. Note also that the results you see are not generally in sequential order, since they depend on how `ParallelTable` schedules the computations to available kernels. As to the original example, here is a modified version,

```
SetSharedVariable[j]
Monitor[ParallelTable[Pause[RandomReal[{0.5, 4.}]];j = i, {i, 1, 10}], j]
```

where the intervals to pause are random, so that not all kernels finish computing at the same time.

**EDIT**

As mentioned by @Szabolcs in the comments,

- You could use `j++` in place of `j=i`, if you are mostly interested in the overall progress
- One should be aware of what type of communication overhead this induces.

Here is one way to find out:

```
j = 0;
First@AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[j++, {i, 1, 1000}];]/1000
```

which returns `0.0028` on my machine.

Comment: It would be more useful to increment `j` every time a value is computed.  This way one could monitor how many values have already been computed out of the total.  The order of computations can be just about anything, so looking at the "current value" of `n` is not very informative.

Comment: Accessing a shared variable took ~10 ms last time I checked.  To have a feel for it, this could introduce a 1 second overhead per 100 elements computed.  But don't take my word for it, benchmark!

Comment: @Szabolcs Agree that using `j++` would probably make more sense, if one is interested in the overall progress only. As to the overhead - yes, sure, that's why I mentioned that it may make sense when the computation for each single `i` is intensive.

Comment: When you're calculating a long list you could decrease the overhead by incrementing `j` only during some of the iterations (for example when `Mod[i,10]==0` or so).

Comment: @Heike Yes, sure, although it may be tricky depending on how the tasks are scheduled to the parallel kernels - they need not at all be sequential. But I wasn't concerned with the exact scheme, since this depends on the particular problem - I was just illustrating a general idea.

Comment: I found this trick does not work if the evaluation inside ParallelTable uses a package. You need to ParallelNeeds["package`"] to make it work.

Comment: @ablmf This isn't specific to this particular case, I think.

Answer (score 10):

Modifying some ideas suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7352461/monitoring-progress-of-a-parallel-computation-in-mathematica), and a suggestions from Leonid in the comments:

```
SetAttributes[monitorParallelTable,HoldAll]
monitorParallelTable[expr_,iter__List,updatethreshold_]:=
 Module[{counter=1,thresh=updatethreshold},
  SetSharedVariable[counter];
  ParallelEvaluate[localcounter=1;];
  Monitor[
   ParallelTable[
    If[localcounter>=thresh,counter=counter+localcounter;localcounter=1,
     localcounter++];expr,iter],
   counter]
 ]
```

Basically, each kernel keeps a working tally of the number of elements it's solved, which dumps to a shared counter once it crosses an adjustable threshold. For example:

```
monitorParallelTable[Pause[RandomReal[{0.5, 4.}]]; n, {n, 5000}, 2]
```

Also, this should work for nested `Table`, e.g.

```
monitorParallelTable[Pause[RandomReal[{0.5, 4.}]]; n, {n, 5000}, {m,300}, 2]
```

A quick check on `AbsoluteTiming` shows the performance hit as a function of the threshold value:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit** Not entirely sure why, but the counter that is monitored goes from 1 to (Maximum Iterations)/(number of kernels) rather than from 1 to (Maximum iterations)

Comment: There's probably some way to work this out for an arbitrary Parallel computation, but I'm not quite sure how to do that (i.e. somehow inject the `If` statement into arbitrary parallel code).

Comment: The problem seems to be (from the look at it, I did not test) that your `expr` evaluates before you pass it to `monitorParallelTable`, so I suspect that both your methods of pausing are equally ineffective simply because the `CompoundExpression` evaluates too early and you actually pass just `n` (that is, if `n` did not have a global value). I think, you need some `Hold*` - attribute here, perhaps `HoldAll`, to make this work.

Comment: The strange thing is, sometimes `Pause` works, sometimes it's as you described. First a pause, then a rapid evaluation. Other times it seems to run on the parallel kernels. I've never really quite worked out how the `Hold` business functions. Where would I put it?

Comment: Just add a line `SetAttributes[monitorParallelTable,HoldAll]` before your main code. As to `Hold*`-attributes, search on Stack Overflow Mathematica tag, there were a couple of good threads on them there. Here is one I remember about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856177/preventing-evaluation-of-mathematica-expressions

Comment: Thanks guys for the many answers. I like the `monitorParallelTable` solution: its use is quite transparent. The only thing is that i usually run `ParallelTable` on many indices: `ParallelTable[expr,{i,1,imax},{j,1,jmax},...]`. Could you generalize monitorParallelTable to this case? Thanks

Comment: @Valerio The local counter doesn't depend on iterated variables, so it should work just as well for this case.

Comment: @Valerio Just added a small tweak to ensure all the table variations pass through the function.

Comment: @EliLansey Thanks, now it works fine!

Comment: @EliLansey In the example `ParallelTable[expr,{i,1,imax},{j,1,jmax}]`, monitorParallelTable goes from `1` to `imax jmax`. Would it be possible to have the monitor index go from, say, 1 to 100? That would help to understand the percentage of computation that is completed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is my final code for implementing a long calculation (demonstrated here over a plane of values) to ensure that all processors are being used and code to monitor the progress, with estimates of time remaining. The last line exports the data to a location specified in that line, so that you can easily come back to it and use it later.

```
(* First define your function using this format f[x_,z_], presumably \
you may have many function definitions that build off of one another, \
this is where the physics goes *)
f[x_, z_] := N[Sin[ x z]]
(* Now define the boundaries of the plane that you wish to calculate \
values over *)
xmin = 1;
xmax = 2 \[Pi];
zmin = 1;
zmax = 8;
(* Now define how many points you wish to calculate the function \
along each axis, note that the total number of calculatons will be \
xstep*ystep.
I reccomend running this prelminarily with a small number of points \
(ie 10 x 10) to determine the average time per point, so that you may \
predict how many points will take a given amout of time *)
xstep = 100;
zstep = 100;
(* You shouldn't have to touch any of the code from 1here1 to, unless \
you want to run several of these statement and are worried about the \
names of the various tables, in which case rename tab1, but don't \
forget to change the name in the export command *)
timestart = AbsoluteTime[];
counter = 0;
SetSharedVariable[counter];
PrintTemporary[Dynamic[
   "Percent Completed: " <> 
    ToString[N[(counter*100)/((xstep + 1) (zstep + 1))]]
    <> "% \nTime elapsed: " <> ToString[AbsoluteTime[] - timestart] <>
     " s \nEstimated Time remaining: " <> 
    ToString[(((xstep + 1) (zstep + 1) - counter) (AbsoluteTime[] - 
        timestart))/counter]
   ]];
tab1 = ParallelTable[counter++; 
   N[f[x, z]], {x, xmin, xmax, N[Abs[xmin - xmax]/xstep]}, {z, zmin, 
    zmax, N[Abs[zmin - zmax]/zstep]}];
timeend = AbsoluteTime[];
Print["Total calculation time: ", timeend - timestart, " s"]
Print["Average time per data point: ", (
 timeend - timestart)/((xstep + 1) (zstep + 1)), " s"]
(* 1here1 *)
(* Change the location and file name, I suggest something that is \
meaningful and you will be able to remember easily *) 
Export["C:\\Users\\Ben\\Documents\\Code for group\\example.dat", tab1]
```