# PrintTemporary in ParallelTable

Tags: parallelization, version-7

I thought of a possible answer to [Monitor doesn't work with ParallelTable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1548/121) but it doesn't work as I hoped it would.

This accumulates print cells instead of deleting them as intended.  Can it be fixed?

```
ParallelTable[
  NotebookDelete[x]; x = PrintTemporary[i];
  Pause[1]; i,
  {i, 1, 15}
]
```

I thought that `x` would be local to each kernel, and this would print four cells (for four cores) that would be deleted and replaced with each iteration.

I then thought that the value of `x` was lost between iterations, but this also fails to delete the print cells:

```
ParallelTable[
  x = PrintTemporary[i]; NotebookDelete[x];
  Pause[1]; i,
  {i, 1, 15}
]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will display a list that's updated as long as the calculation runs, and vanishes afterwards:

```
(* Pattern that translates the kernel's ID to
   a number from 1 to $KernelCount *)
kernels = ParallelTable[$KernelID -> i, {i, $KernelCount}];
SetSharedVariable[kernels]; (* for Mathematica 7 *)

(* This is the list that will display each kernel's current operation *)
SetSharedVariable[currentNumber]
currentNumber = ConstantArray[0, Length@kernels];

PrintTemporary["Current calculations:"];
PrintTemporary@Dynamic[currentNumber];

(* Start the computation *)
ParallelTable[
    Pause@RandomReal[{0, .25}]; (* Long calculation *)
    currentNumber[[$KernelID /. kernels]] = i,
    {i, 100},
    Method -> "FinestGrained"
]
```

The immediate output looks like this:

> `Current calculations:`
>
> ```
> {15, 24, 16, 23, 25, 29, 27, 20}
> ```

Now wait for `ParallelTable` to finish, and the above will disappear, leaving only the result:

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ...}
> ```

You can modify the `Dynamic` statement according to your needs of course, such as adding a `// Column` to the argument to print it nicer etc.