# How to simultaneously monitoring parallel computations in different Kernels?

Tags: parallelization, monitoring

I have a question about monitoring parallel processes. Let's suppose that I am running the following code with 5 active Kernels.

```
ParallelDo[For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, Print[i]], {k, 1, 5, 1}]
```

Every kernel will pick a number from 1 to 5 of the `ParallelDo` loop command and will execute the internal loop `For` individually. How can I monitor with a `ProgressIndicator` bar every single Kernel evaluation status simultaneously?

Comment: Are you looking for something different than [Parallel Kernel Status](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/ParallelKernelStatus.html)?

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a way to monitor the evolution of the parameter "i" in the "For" cycle, independently for every Kernel. At the moment I am doing it by using the "Print" command, the problem is that it prints a new line every time, while I would like some kind of a monitor that auto-update himself without printing a new line every time. Looking on other questions I found that is exactly what "ProgressIndicator" does, but I am not able to use it the way I wanted. Do you have any suggestion on how to do so? Thanks.

Comment: You should have a look at this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1562/21606

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid that somebody might miss the reference in my comment, I would like to rephrase the solution which is given [in this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1562/21606) by @David.

Basically, one sets up a list - `currentStep` - which holds the current value of the iterators on every kernel (or some combination that gives the desired output) and is printed temporarily as a `Dynamic` construct. By this, one avoids huge amounts of `Print` cells in the notebook that need to be deleted afterwards.

Mainly, the correct assignment in the body needs to be like `currentStep[[$KernelID /. kernels]] = i` where `i` is the iterator. For the example given in the OP (where the iterator of the inner `For` loop needs to be monitored) we can proceed like this:

```
kernels = ParallelTable[$KernelID -> i, {i, $KernelCount}];
currentStep = ConstantArray[0, Length@kernels];
SetSharedVariable[kernels, currentStep];

PrintTemporary["Current computation on each kernel:"];
PrintTemporary@Dynamic[currentStep//Column];

ParallelDo[For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++, Pause[.25]; currentStep[[$KernelID/.kernels]] = "Kernel: " <> ToString[$KernelID] <> " -> i=" <> ToString[i]], {k, 1, 20, 1}]
```