# Shared variable impacting speed?

Tags: parallelization

I am using a shared variable as a progress indicator ( via `SetSharedVariable[counter]` and then `Dynamic[counter]`), to keep track of a parallel computation. However, there seems to be a massive overhead just because I ask ParallelTable to increment the counter:

```
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[(counter++; myCompiledFunction),{i,1000}];]

(* {6.580984, Null} *)
```

But the same exact computation without the counter is about 50 times faster:

```
AbsoluteTiming[ParallelTable[myCompiledFunction,{i,1000}];]

(* {0.129618, Null} *)
```

Does anybody know why, and if there is a solution? Note: this does not happen if I use `Table`, but then I cannot take advantage of all my cores.

Comment: `SetSharedFunction` and `SetSharedVariable` force the function or variable to be evaluated by the main kernel (not subkernels).  Every single time `counter++` is evaluated, the subkernel will pause and wait for the main kernel to finish this evaluation.  In your example this means that bidirectional communication between the main kernel and subkernels will be forced 1000 times, even if you use `Method -> "CoarsestGrained"`.  (And this commununication is costly: one should always try to minimize it.)  Just don't use `SetSharedVariable` if performance is important.

Comment: Understood, thanks.

Comment: Related: [Monitor doesn't work with ParallelTable](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/monitor-doesnt-work-with-paralleltable).  (The OP may have gotten the approach from this post.)

Comment: @Ziofil You may be interested in the "Possible Issues" section of [`ParallelSubmit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ParallelSubmit.html), which shows some of the overheads costs (through examples).